# ASP.NET MVC 3: HTTP Post parameter allways null after deployment

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, http, parameters, null

I've created a small website in ASP.NET MVC 3, and it works fine in debugenvironment.

After deployment (on a https website) the website gives problems and after figuring a while, it seems that the HTTPPOST parameters are allways null ...

I'll provide some information:

the .cshtml:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Registration", "Home", FormMethod.Post)){
<div id="middle">        
    <div id="radio">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {    
            <input type="radio" id="@string.Format("radio{0}", item.ID)" name="radio" value="@item.ID" /><label for="@string.Format("radio{0}", item.ID)">@item.Description</label>
        }
    </div>
    <div id="divOverig">
        <label for="overig">
            Overig:</label>
        <input style="float:right; width:70%;" type="text" id="overig" name="overig" />
    </div>
</div>
<div id="end">
</div>
<div id="left">
    @Html.ActionLink("Terug", "Device")
</div>
<div id="right">
    <input type="submit" id="next" value="Naar apparaat informatie" />
</div>
```

}

The controller:

```
 public ActionResult Problem(string radio, string overig){ ... }
```

In debug environment the parameters are correctly filled and passed. On the webserver the parameter is allways empty.

When I change the POST in GET is works fine, but I want to use the POST (later in the website I use complex types).

Anyone a brilliant idea?

Comment: Of course the controller is : public ActionResult Registration(string radio, string overig){ ... }

Comment: The action method is not the one where the forms submits to. Anyway, try debugging it on the localhost with https support. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/04/22/better-faster-easier-ssl-testing-for-asp-net-mvc-amp-webforms.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This problem is caused by the secure environment (https).

I put the website on a normal environment (http) and it works flawless ;)

Thanx for you're time.

Answer (score 1):

decorate the ActionResult with `HttpPost`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Registration(string radio, string overig){ ... }
```

Comment: After I did this, I get an error page: 
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


 The resource cannot be found. 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Home/Registation/

Comment: look at the error message closely requested url is /Home/**Registation**/ where as the ActionResults name is **Registration** there is a typo

Comment: Sorry, that was my typo fault... Is definitly says Registration